# Como desabilitar o submit de um form por "Enter" - c# MVC

Tags: c#, mvc, webforms, formulário-submeter

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto web em c#, e para os forms estou usando o `Html.BeginForm`. Como desabilitar o submit ao pressionar a tecla *Enter*? Dá pra fazer sem javascript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sem `javascript` eu acho difícil conseguir, tu vai precisar de um `script Client Side` pra verificar o clique. Com `jQuery` pode fazer o seguinte:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form#exemplo').bind("keypress", function(e) {
        if ((e.keyCode == 10)||(e.keyCode == 13)) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

ou

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form#exemplo').keypress(function(e) {
        if ((e.keyCode == 10)||(e.keyCode == 13)) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Se tu tiver um botão de Submit neste teu formulário ele deve estar marcado como "default" e a ação de teclar o Enter executa o componente marcado como tal.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode também transformar o submit em button.

```
<input type='button'>
```

E submeter o form via JS.

```
$('#form_id').submit();
```